# Formatting dynamic dates in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am working on HTML emails in which there is a date section where I want to place a placeholder as it's a dynamic data.

The HTML code where I am using dates are:

```
<tr>
   <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">when:</td>
   <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 8%;">Mar 28/18 @ 7:00pm to <br> Mar 30/18 @ 7:00pm</td>
</tr>
```

#### Problem

I am wondering in place of `Mar 28/18 @ 7:00pm to <br> Mar 30/18 @ 7:00pm`, what placeholder do I need to format the date variables properly?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type your dynamic date data have, you need to take different actions.

#### Formatting Carbon instances

```php
{{ $start->format('M d/y @ h:ma') }} to <br> {{ $end->format('M d/y @ h:ma') }}
```

#### Formatting vanilla timestamps

```php
{{ date('M d/y @ h:ma', $start) }} to <br> {{ date('M d/y @ h:ma', $end) }}
```

#### Formatting valid date strings

```php
{{ date('M d/y @ h:ma', strtotime($start)) }} to <br> {{ date('M d/y @ h:ma', strtotime($end)) }}
```

#### Formatting dates using custom Blade directives

Extend Blade for a new `@datetime` directive. Add a `BladeServiceProvider` and register the directive in its `boot` method.

You can also be lazy and add it to already existing `AppServiceProvider`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BladeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('datetime', function ($expression) {
            return "<?php echo ($expression)->format('M d/y @ h:ma'); ?>";
        });
    }
}
```

With that in place and considering Carbon instances, your view code would be:

```php
@datetime($start) to @datetime($end)
```

Needless to say that you can easily adapt the code for other date types.

Comment: your answer seems to be good but I am wondering if we can use simply `{{$date_from}}` to `{{$date_to}}` ?

Comment: Sure you can. Format the dates already in your controller code and then pass 'em to the view. `{{ }}` is only used to print out escaped variables, nothing more. AFAIK, it's not extendable in the way you have in mind.

Comment: As we are using php to dynamically pass the data.